# cast Long to BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How can I cast `Long` to `BigDecimal`?

Comment: You can't cast one to the other.  They aren't subclasses of a common superclass.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You'll have to create a new `BigDecimal`.

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(long);
```

Answer (score 24):

For completeness you can use:

```
// valueOf will return cached instances for values zero through to ten
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(yourLong);
```

0 - 10 is as of the java 6 implementation, not sure about previous JDK's

Comment: valueOf is preferred as per the JavaDocs: 'This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (long) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigDecimal values.'

Answer (score 17):

**You should not use BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(long); !!**

The implementation in BigDecimal for longs is not precise.
For financial applications this is critical!

But the implementation for the String argument is better!
So use something like:

```
new BigDecimal(yourLong.toString());
```

There was a talk on http://www.parleys.com/ about this.

Comment: I realise this is a little late in the day, but do you have any of a more direct link to the source of this claim, because looking at the source to BigDecimal in JDK7 it seems at best out of date.

Comment: It's been a while, all I remember is on parley's they made this claim, but I cannot find the link any more. Maybe in JDK7 this is already optimized.

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast it.  You can create a new `BigDecimal` though.  You can get a `long` from a `Long` using `Long.getLongValue()` if you have the non-primitave Long.

```
BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal(longVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new BigDecimal object

```
  Long test = new Long (10);
  BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal(test.longValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new bigDecimal

[how to do it](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(long))